# Display column header containing highest value in a spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

So, I have a list of names and values, linked here:

[image: Spreadsheet]

Ideally, I want to locate the highest value in the spreadsheet, and then display the name of the person with the highest value overall.

So far, in, say, the 'Tuesday' row, I've been able to select the highest value, and getting the name 'Frank', who has the highest value, using this formula...

=INDEX($B$1:$M$1,MATCH(MAX(B4:M4),B4:M4,0))

...and then changing it accordingly for each other 'day'.

What I want to do is select the name of the person with the absolute highest value over all of the 'days'.

In the attached example, it would be "Joseph" with a value of "589".

I know that I can use MAX(B2:M8) to get the highest value of "589" displayed in a cell, which is perfect, but now I want to display the actual name of that person who got the highest value, which in this example would be "Joseph".

How would I go about doing that?

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What if there's a tie. Two different people having same max scores?

Comment: Since you can't attach a file here, I assume that you also asked this question in a different forum, where you CAN attach files. In the interest of not wasting people's time trying to answer a question that may already have an answer somewhere else, please post links to all other cross posts.

Comment: Hi @Jeff Caron,, formula works on data orientation,, please [edit] your post & share some sample data,, also be specific about your need better show the expected result,, and measures in case of tie !!

Comment: @Jeff Caron - As I see the edit trail, the snapshot that you posted originally was good enough. You may like to insert it again. Spreadsheet[1] is not linked and even if you do so, users may not download it for security reasons.

Comment: Hey @Jeff Caron,, check my post,, I've altered your formula and is working ☺

Answer (score 1):

1] In `B1:M1` housed the person name and `B2:M8` housed of your value

2] Name of person who got the highest value of the days

In `O2`, enter formula :

```
=INDEX(B1:M1,SUMPRODUCT((B2:M8=MAX(B2:M8))*COLUMN(A1:L1)))
```

[image]

**Edit #.1**

If the max value have duplicate, then formula changed to >>

In `O2`, enter array formula (Shift+Ctrl+Enter)

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,INDEX(B1:M1,N(IF(1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(A1:L1)/(B2:M8=MAX(B2:M8)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIF(B2:M8,MAX(B2:M8)))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: What is the use of `COLUMN(A1:L1)))`  , Y u have skip  Column `M` ? Since `COLUMN(B1:M1)))` covers all data !!

Comment: =COLUMN(A1:L1) return ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12} , or you can use =COLUMN(B1:M1)-COLUMN(A1) also return ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}

Comment: ,, I got, thanks but one more issue which is always possible what is `Name 7` ,, `Day 2` also has `589` !

Comment: Name 7 ,, Day 2... are the column header and row header name. 589 is the highest value as mentioned in the OP's post. All header's names and values are estimated because unable to see the OP's screenshot layout.

Comment: Noo,, in previous comment it should like,, `what IF Name 7 ,, Day 2 also has 589`. I mean to say if  `589` is also `cell H3` (if the Max value is Duplicate),,  formula is expected to return `NAME 7` and `Joseph`,, this is what I was suppose to ask,, sorry for that one !

Comment: Please see my edited post formula for the duplicate max value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106631/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-bosco-yip).

Comment: For the *second, third*, etc MAX value, use AGGREGATE instead of SUMPRODUCT.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to try a user defined function, this one will do the job:

```
Function GetHighEarner(Target As Range) As String

Dim MyStr As String
Dim MyMax As Long, i As Long
Dim MyArr As Variant

MyArr = Target
MyMax = Application.Max(MyArr)
For i = LBound(MyArr, 2) To UBound(MyArr, 2)
    If Application.Max(Application.Index(MyArr, , i)) = MyMax Then
        If Len(MyStr) < 1 Then
                MyStr = MyArr(1, i)
                Else
                MyStr = MyStr & ", " & MyArr(1, i)
        End If
    End If
Next i

GetHighEarner = MyStr

End Function
```

Just ALT F11 to enter the developer menu, insert a module and paste the function into the module then use it in the sheet using:
=GetHighEarner(B1:M8) (from your example, any range should work)
as normal in the sheet.
The function assumes that you have included the header rows (names) in the range. Any name that has a match for the highest value in the range will be returned.

Comment: Nice job @Justin Doward,, is working +1 ☺

Answer (score 0):

Consider not doing it all in one formula. In each column create the MAX() for that column, say in row 1. Then you can create a Max for row 1 and use a lookup to find which column in row 1 has that value.

If there are several columns with the same Max value, only the first one will be shown, of course, so you will need to work on some solution for ties.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- Formula in Cell `F44`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX($B$43:$E$43,MATCH(MAX($B$44:$E$50),B44:E44,0)),"")
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*