# Excel help - how to pull in a column heading to a cell based on data in a row that contains that column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have created an Excel doc for the prices of various video hardware. I have a field on the left that lists the hardware. Across the top I have a row of the various stores where I have sought prices. Under each store I list their price for each piece of hardware.

This is what the spreadsheet looks like:

[image: This is what the spreadsheet looks like.]

I have two final columns:

1. Calculate which price is the cheapest by this formula: `=MIN(E5:N5)`
2. Cheapest price location: this I can't seem to work out the formula for - I need this to locate the cheapest price then pull in the data that is at the top of that column, i.e. the name of the store. I'm assuming I'll need to use an IF function, just can't work out how!

Comment: See if any of the answers here help. You may need to slightly alter the solutions given therein to change Excel function from MAX to MIN most likely.  Link to the question - https://superuser.com/questions/1541139/display-column-header-containing-highest-value-in-a-spreadsheet/1541143#1541143

Comment: A bit larger copy of your spreadsheet might help. An example with the answer in one case would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a MIN price value already calculated you'll want to use a MATCH function to figure out the column that contains that lowest price:

```
 MATCH(CellWithMinPriceCalculated, CellRangeOfAllPrices, 0)
```

So if I had all my prices for each vendor in row 6, columns D through Z then my minimum price calculated as MIN(D6:Z6) value in C6 then I'd use:

```
MATCH(C6, D6:Z6,0)
```

Combine this with an INDEX into your row of vendor names. If I had all vendor names in a single row (3) in columns D through Z I would use:

```
=INDEX(D3:Z3, 1, CalculatedMATCHValue)
```

So combined it would be:

```
=INDEX(D3:Z3, 1, MATCH(C6, D6:Z6,0))
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks for this. That's the solution. Cheers!